# KeyError: 0 when using ciclo for en folium

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory, folium

I'm in the geopanda tutorial, in the plotting with folium section (add markers).

I currently have a geodataframe called geo_df and my code is as follows

```
geo_df_list = [[point.xy[1][0], point.xy[0][0]] for point in geo_df.geometry ]

# Iterate through list and add a marker for each volcano, color-coded by its type.
i = 0
for coordinates in geo_df_list:
    #assign a color marker for the type of volcano, Strato being the most common
    if geo_df.Type[i] == "Stratovolcano":
        type_color = "green"
    elif geo_df.Type[i] == "Complex volcano":
        type_color = "blue"
    elif geo_df.Type[i] == "Shield volcano":
        type_color = "orange"
    elif geo_df.Type[i] == "Lava dome":
        type_color = "pink"
    else:
        type_color = "purple"


    # Place the markers with the popup labels and data
    map.add_child(folium.Marker(location = coordinates,
                            popup =
                            "Year: " + str(geo_df.Year[i]) + '<br>' +
                            "Name: " + str(geo_df.Name[i]) + '<br>' +
                            "Country: " + str(geo_df.Country[i]) + '<br>'
                            "Type: " + str(geo_df.Type[i]) + '<br>'
                            "Coordinates: " + str(geo_df_list[i]),
                            icon = folium.Icon(color = "%s" % type_color)))
    i = i + 1
```

**I don't understand why I get this error**

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3362             except KeyError as err:

5 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
3364
3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 0

Comment: I don't know if this is a correct comment since the data is not presented, but if `geo_df.Type[i]` is used to determine the type of volcano, I think you need to specify `.loc` or something similar if you are using rows to determine the type. Also, it is possible that the reserved word for Type is causing the problem, so try renaming it something else.